# Prevent GIL from being released

Tags: python

I'm attempting to call into the python interpreter from C.  This is working properly, but the python code that is being run is releasing the GIL, allowing other threads to proceed, but I want the python code to execute atomically.  Is there a way to prevent the GIL from being released?